# get column index for furthest row value to the right in a matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain the value of a column that corresponds to the furthest value to the right in my dataset (which is completely binary):

```
Variable 1 2 3 4 5 
   A     0 0 1 0 1
   B     0 1 0 0 0
   C     1 0 0 1 0
   D     1 1 1 1 1
```

So for the matrix above I would like to know the highest value for variable A (in this case 5), variable B (2), variable C (4), etc.  I'm not sure where to start with this problem - anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `max.col`:

```
max.col(m, "last") 
# 5 2 4 5
```

Type `?max.col` to see details on how this works.

---

Data:

```
m <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
  0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = 4:5, .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
  "B", "C", "D"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
#   1 2 3 4 5
# A 0 0 1 0 1
# B 0 1 0 0 0
# C 1 0 0 1 0
# D 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `apply` in row-mode and find the largest index in each row of your matrix:

```
M = matrix( 
    c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
    nrow=4, 
    ncol=5) 

maxVals <- apply(M, 1, function(x) {
                           y <- max(c(1:length(x))[x==1])
                           return(y)
                       })

> maxVals
[1] 5 2 4 5
```